# php variable save to file

Tags: php, fopen

I'm new in using PHP and I would like ask for this question;

I have variable

```
$content = $recfile[0]['name'];
```

This variable $content include name selected from mysql DB.

I would like variable $content save to the file.
I used:

```
 $fp = fopen(DIR_PATH . "\\public\\temp\\myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

I don't know where is the mistake. I tried various options as serialize or var_export but nothing worked.

Comment: What is the result that you receive or error message that you get?  Do you need the double backslashes in the path or would single ones work?

Comment: Tim's questions are good.  It sounds like your file isn't actually getting opened (via fopen) for writing to.

Comment: Aren't the double backslashes necessary simply for escaping backslash within a double-quoted string literal?

Comment: What is the value of `$recfile[0]['name']`? If it's a string or number, you don't need to serialize it. Your code should work as long as you have permission to create the output file.

Comment: this value $recfile[0]['name'] is always string

Comment: Why is this question tagged MySQL?  Have you verified the value of `DIR_PATH . "\\public\\temp\\myText.txt"`?  Have you inspected your error log?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing to a linux file system, you should use forward slashes

```
 $fp = fopen(DIR_PATH . "/public/temp/myText.txt","wb");
```

You should also check if fopen worked.  If `fopen` failed, the value of $fp will be false

```
if($fp) {
  //code to write to the file
}
```

Comment: oops, I missed that part :). Edited my response.

Comment: I use Wamp server on windows 7

Comment: When i use fwrite($fp,"blah blah"); evrything is OK, but when i used $content its problem, but i Know that $content has value, I use echo $content :)

Comment: If you set `$content = "blah blah"`, does that work?

Comment: That leads me to believe that there's a character or two in `$recfile[0]['name']` that fwrite doesn't like.

Comment: $recfile[0]['name'] include name of person: John, Frank etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if $content does indeed have any content (by f.i. `echo $content;`) and if your constant DIR_PATH holds the right path?

If those are correct, try forward slashes (though escaped backslashes should work)

```
$fp = fopen(DIR_PATH . "/public/temp/myText.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```